# Simplify a recursive function from 3 to 2 clauses

Tags: recursion, f#

I am doing some exercises on F#, i have this function that calculate the alternate sum:

```
let rec altsum = function
    | []         -> 0
    | [x]        -> x
    | x0::x1::xs -> x0 - x1 + altsum xs;; 

val altsum : int list -> int
```

The exercise consist in declare the same function with only two clauses...but how to do this?

Comment: You do realize that this function is not tail recursive, don't you?

Comment: Yes I do, but the exercise do not required it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer of *mydogisbox* is correct and work!

But after some attempts I found a smallest and readable solution of the problem.

```
let rec altsum2 = function
| [] -> 0
| x0::xs -> x0 - altsum2 xs
```

Example

```
altsum2 [1;2;3] essentially do this:
1 - (2 - (3 - 0)
```

it's is a bit tricky but work!

---

**OFF TOPIC:**

Another elegant way to solve the problem, using F# List library is:

```
let altsum3 list = List.foldBack (fun x acc -> x - acc) list 0;;
```

After the comment of phoog I started trying to solve the problem with a tail recursive function:

```
let tail_altsum4 list = 
    let pl l = List.length l % 2 = 0
    let rec rt = function    
        | ([],acc) -> if pl list then -acc else acc
        | (x0::xs,acc) -> rt (xs, x0 - acc)
    rt (list,0)
```

This is also a bit tricky...substraction is not commutative and it's impossible think to revers with `List.rev` a long list...but I found a workaround! :)

Comment: Nice!  I got to my answer and stopped thinking.  Your solution is much better.

Comment: Take it all the way: `let altsum3 list = List.foldBack (-) list 0;;`.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the number of cases, you need to move your algorithm back closer to the original problem. The problem says to negate alternating values, so that's what your solution should do.

```
let altsum lst =
  let rec altsumRec lst negateNext =
    match lst with
    | [] -> 0
    | head::tail -> (if negateNext then -head else head) + altsumRec tail (not negateNext)
  altsumRec lst false
```